# WebView clearCache but leave cookies

Tags: android, caching, webview

I have application which load local html file. That html shows some images from server and have javascript analytics code. OnDestroy function i use webview clearcache method which clears all cache that was stored by that html file, including cookies. Is there any way to delete cache but leave cookies that was created by analytics so I can track returning visitors? Or is there any way to disable caching for images?

Tnx,
j.

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am looking to clear the cache, but keep the cookies.

Comment: unfortunately not yet... but I found other solutions for tracking and abandon this idea